# Rust/MongoDB - bson DateTime to JSON

Tags: mongodb, rust

I'm trying to return a json with a datetime from MongoDB, here is my struct

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
pub struct Management {
  // .. other properties
  #[serde(with = "bson::serde_helpers::chrono_datetime_as_bson_datetime")]
  pub created_at: DateTime<Utc>,
}
```

the problem is that what I'm getting is:

```
{
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": {
     "$numberLong": "1634685582291"
    }
   }
}
```

instead of
`{createdAt: 2021-06-24T04:00:00Z}`
I tried to create my own serialization method but then it was saving strings in the database instead of dates.

Can someone give me hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using Serde's `with`, which is used for both serialization and deserialization. From the [documentation][1]:

```
#[serde(with = "module")]
Combination of serialize_with and deserialize_with. Serde will use $module::serialize as the serialize_with function and $module::deserialize as the deserialize_with function.
```

Edit:

The solution would be to create another structure for the representation of the "outgoing management", where you serialize the date as an ISO string as you want:

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
pub struct ManagementOutgoing {
  // .. other properties
  #[serde(with = "your-serializer")]
  pub created_at: DateTime<Utc>,
}
```

And you can implement the `From` trait for it so that you can easily convert a `Management` instance into a `ManagementOutgoing`.